# Sending WM messages to web browser input

Tags: c#, forms, input, browser, windows-messages

I have here a web browser (OpenWebKitSharp) that goes to a chat room. I'm writing a bot that's very similar to an IRC bot. However, the input field has no submit form or button. Text is only sent by pressing enter, and the Javascript is extremely obfuscated.

How do I a) Get focus of that input field programmatically (Optional if not necessary), and b) How do I send an enter key to that input field c) Do all of this without making the window active?

Either by Javascript, or C#.
If I can't, what are my options?

(I've also tried looking at HTTP, but this chat doesn't seem to use it.)

Comment: Well, if it's a web-based chat it supports HTTP.  You just need to figure out the URLs to request depending on what you want to do.  Alternative, you can use the Web Browser control and gain access to various objects in the page...

Comment: I've used Tamper Data and the Web Console and Fiddler2. I see GET requests for images, but nothing when sending messages.